# SSRS group header expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've created a report in SSRS and have grouped the results by their currency. In the group header section, I'd like for the title to say the name of the currency that is grouped (There are four in total). What expression would I use to do this? The field of the currency dataset is [sCcy_Code].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the grouped field in an expression without any problems or aggregate. Sounds like you are grouping by the sCcy_Code field, so an expression similar to

```
=Switch(
  Fields!sCcy_Code.value = 1, "Dollars"
  Fields!sCcy_Code.value = 2, "Pounds"
  Fields!sCcy_Code.value = 3, "Euro"
  1=1, "Other Currency")
```

This can be set as the expression for the cell, or if you need additional text in the same cell, as the expression of a placeholder.